# How to close a file opened by another thread?

Tags: c#

I've a background thread which loads an image file using `Image.FromFile`, I want to close the opened image file from another thread

Is there a possibility to close a file opened by a background thread in c#?

**Edit**: 
I used this code at first - on the same thread- but I don't know why I can't free the file or delete it, or even the new file which I saved using `img.Save(...)`. So I tried to force closing on another thread. that's why I'm asking this question.

```
var img = Image.FromFile(filepath);
img.Save(filepath + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
img.Dispose();
if (File.Exists(filepath+ ".jpg"))
    File.Delete(+ ".jpg");
if (File.Exists(filepath))
    File.Delete(filepath);
```

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea. Why do you need to force close the file? Your thread is using it!

Comment: Not generally, no. And in this case you would have to dispose of the image object, and even if you could do that the background thread probably wouldn't like it.

Comment: This is one of those rare times where it may be good to ask - why do you need to do this?

Comment: Any thread can call the Image object's Dispose() method.  Interlocking to make sure that no thread is using the object is up to you.

Comment: I'm disposing the image, but the file is still locked. I want to know why...

Comment: Show related code, perhaps you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Sinatr I updated the question with the code

Comment: Closing file in another thread is a wrong solution (which is so typical for [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)). It looks like you are doing it correctly, which `Exception` you get and at which row?

Comment: I'm getting those exceptions:
`A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll`

`A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Answer (score 4):

The file isn't "Closed" until the image has been disposed. Open and close the file immediately in a single step by loading the image with the following snippet:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap image;
using (var fileLoadImage = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg"))
{
    image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fileLoadImage);
}
```

You need to be very careful with this pattern though because you are still going to have to explicitly call `image.Dispose()` when you are finished with your image. At least this will get you around file locking though.

Best of luck!

**EDIT - A Runnable Snippet**

Copy and paste the following into a new Console application to see that it works. Make sure you have a file called "test.jpg" in your sample pictures before you start and you will see this deletes both the original file and the new file just fine:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap image;
        var originalFile = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\test.jpg";
        var newFile = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\test2.jpg";
        using (var fileLoadImage = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(originalFile))
        {
            image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fileLoadImage);
        }

        image.Save(newFile);
        System.IO.File.Delete(originalFile);

        image.Dispose();
        System.IO.File.Delete(newFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Please check it.
I also tried to use a `MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath));`
but I can't also delete the file, although I'm calling Close, then Dispose, on MemoryStream and the image i got from `Image.FromStream`

Comment: @donfoneseo I wrote a sample program and everything works exactly as expected. I pasted the code into my edited answer for you to play around with. I recommend checking if some other part of the application is using the file. If you are starting background threads, possibly multiple threads are accessing that same file? Anyways - things are working as expected!